# Can't print first and last character of code

Tags: python

Hey guys so I have my program working to a certain extent. My program is suppose to check if there is an `"A"` in the user input and if done so it will swap that `"A"` with the next letter.

Here are the examples:

```
"tan" = "TNA"
"abracadabra" = "BARCADABARA"
"whoa" = "WHOA"
"aardvark" = "ARADVRAK"
"eggs" = "EGGS"
"a" = "A"
```

In my case this is what works and doesn't work:

Works:

```
tan to TNA
```

Doesn't work:

```
abracadabra = BARCADABAR
whoa = WHO
aardvark = ARADVRA
eggs = EGG

a =
```

`a` just equals nothing.

What I'm getting at is that the last character isn't printing and I'm not sure how to do so.

```
def scrambleWord(userInput):
    count = 0
    Word_ = ""
    firstLetter_ = ""
    secondLetter_ = ""
    while count < len(userInput):
        if count+1 >=len(userInput):
            break #copy last character
        firstLetter_ = userInput[count] #assigning first letter
        secondLetter_ = userInput[count+1] #assigning next letter
        if firstLetter_ == 'A' and secondLetter_ != 'A':
            Word_ += (secondLetter_ + firstLetter_) #Swap then add both letters
            count+=1
        else:
            Word_+=firstLetter_
        count+=1
    return Word_


def main():
    userInput = input("Enter a word: ")
    finish = scrambleWord(userInput.upper())
    print(finish)

main()
```

Comment: Your comment at the `break` in your `while` loop is *copy last character*. But there is no code outside the `while` loop that actually does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you are just breaking without writing the userinput[count] into the word.

```
if count+1 >=len(userInput):
            Word_ += userInput[count]
            break #copy last character
```

This should help